# Angular <base href="./path"> ignored for static resources

Tags: javascript, angular

I am not completely sure if this is wrong or not, but when I generate prod build with angular:

```
"ng  build --outputPath=.. --base-href="./path" --prod"
```

the static resources are still fetch from ./ root like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ask</title>
  <base href="./path">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css"></head>
 <body>
   <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a5dd35324ddfd942bef1.js">
  </script><script type="text/javascript" src="es2015-polyfills.358ed1827c991dd2afb0.js" nomodule></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.407a467dedb63cfdd103.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.d1ac828f1974a06a0fe5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Shouldn't it be prefixed with base-href?

```
href="path/styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css"
src="path/runtime.a5dd35324ddfd942bef1.js
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up here searching for a solution where we have a fixed

```
<base href="/APP-NAME">
```

in the index file. The statement of JanS "That way the browser does the prefixing when fetching the resources" triggered me that something was wrong, because the styles.css was fetched from the url without the "/APP-NAME" added, from https://localhost:43468/styles.css instead of https://localhost:43468/APP-NAME/styles.css.

Now that I write it down it seems pretty obvious, we needed to add the slash at the end:

```
<base href="/APP-NAME/">
```

The misleading issue here was that it worked when we started our .NET Core Angular application from Visual Studio 2017, but didn't work anymore when using Visual Studio 2019. It appeared that starting the app with Visual Studio 2017 on IIS Express launches the app both on 
https://localhost:43468
and 
https://localhost:43468/APP-NAME
Therefore it worked to retrieve the static resources from the 'wrong' url. They seem to have fixed the issue of starting 2 ulr's in IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

The `--base-href "xyz"` (notice the missing `=`) option should generate a `<base href="xyz">` in the `<head>` of your `index.html`.

That way the browser does the prefixing when fetching the resources.

Comment: I updated the question for u to see whole index.html. I have <base href="./path"> in index.html but resources are not prefixed with "./path"

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the equal sign and quotes from the command.

```
ng  build --outputPath=.. --base-href ./path --prod
```

Comment: Still getting the same index.html, It did not help